# How to get data from an api having XML content using react

Tags: reactjs, axios

Not able to figure out how to get data from an api having XML Content. I tried using axios,with JSON everything is clear.
I want the data to be fetched from api on load and respective values to be filled in the form fields.

Answer (score 2):

```
fetch(URL).then((results) => {
  // results returns XML. Cast this to a string, then create
  // a new DOM object out of it! like this
  results
    .text()
    .then(( str ) => {
      let responseDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'application/xml');
     }
  });
```

You can also use  [NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-xml-parser)  to parse XML.